# DisplayField overflow ellipsis in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs5

I want to set text-overflow : ellipsis in displayField, but when add a large text, displayfield groving horizontally.

displayField:

```
 xtype: 'displayfield',
        border: 1,
        style: {
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderStyle: 'solid'
        },
        maxHeight:50,
        cls:'custom-field',
        height:50,
        width: 100,
        value: 'this is <br/> a multiline text<br/> and it should be ended <br/>with three dots when overflowY',
```

css class:

```
.custom-field{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

example on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ole

Comment: check `line-clamp`  https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: if you don't want or can't do it in CSS, there is an ext method to format a string with an ellipsis : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-ellipsis